# Showing the MCBrowserViewController in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, multipeer-connectivity

So, I’ve been trying to get the MCBrowserViewController to appear, but I’ve had no luck. I’m trying to create this in an appp I’m developing for iOS. Can anyone help? Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import MultipeerConnectivity

var peerID: MCPeerID!
var mcSession: MCSession!
var mcAdvertiserAssistant: MCAdvertiserAssistant!
var foundPeers = [MCPeerID]()



PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class viewcontroller: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
var serviceBrowser : MCBrowserViewController!
func startBrowsingForPeer()  {
    serviceBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "hws-ridleyn", session: mcSession)

    serviceBrowser.delegate.self

}



peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
mcSession = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .none)
mcSession.delegate.self

class ViewController: UIViewController, MCSessionDelegate, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {



let session = MCSession(peer: peerID, 
                        securityIdentity: nil, 
                        encryptionPreference: .none)



func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
    switch state {
    case MCSessionState.connected:
        print("Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
    case MCSessionState.connecting:
        print("Connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")
    case MCSessionState.notConnected:
        print("Not Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
    }
}

func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withDiscoveryInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    foundPeers.append(peerID)

    print(browser)
    browser.startBrowsingForPeers()

}


func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            print("image recieved")
        }
    }
}
func sendImage(img: UIImage) {
    if mcSession.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
        if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
            do {
                try mcSession.send(imageData, toPeers: mcSession.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Send error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                present(ac, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
}
func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {
}
    func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL?, withError error: Error?) {
    }
func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
            dismiss(animated: true)
        }
func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}


func startHosting(action: UIAlertAction!) {
    mcAdvertiserAssistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "hws-ridleyn", discoveryInfo: nil, session: mcSession)
    mcAdvertiserAssistant.start()
}
func joinSession(action: UIAlertAction!) {
    let mcBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "hws-ridleyn", session: mcSession)
    mcBrowser.delegate = self
    present(mcBrowser, animated: true)
}

let vc = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))


// your view controller here
}


let vcc = ViewController()
vcc.startHosting(action: nil)
ViewController.startHosting(vcc)

   }
}
extension viewcontroller : MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {
func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

   }

}


PlaygroundPage.current
```

If you’re wondering, I’ve done lots of research, but I’m not really understanding this, I’ve also looked at apple’s documentation, but that doesn’t give me a suitable example. I asked a question like this before but I didn’t get an answer that i could use for reference. So if you can, can you post your answer but with my current code attached to it, please?

Answer (score 2):

Your playground code is a little bit of a mess, but here's a clearer example of how to set up classes of this type:

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

class MPCPeripheralViewController: UIViewController {

    private let peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
    private var mcBrowser: MCBrowserViewController?
    private var mcSession: MCSession!
    private var outputStream: OutputStream?

    // MARK: Class methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create a session - Using the arguments you require
        mcSession = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .required)
        mcSession.delegate = self
    }

    // Hook this up to a button - use it to show the browser
    @IBAction func connectButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // The MCBrowserView is nicely set up for us in situation - so we don't need any custom views
        mcBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "StackOverflow", session: mcSession)

        guard let mcBrowser = mcBrowser else {
            print("Couldn't create mcBrowser!")
            return
        }

        mcBrowser.delegate = self
        present(mcBrowser, animated: true)
    }

    func joinSession() {
        guard mcSession.connectedPeers.count > 0 else {
            print("No connected peers")
            return
        }

        outputStream = try? mcSession.startStream(withName: "control", toPeer: mcSession.connectedPeers.first!)

        guard let outputStream = outputStream else {
            print("Output stream is nil")
            return
        }

        outputStream.delegate = self
        outputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode:RunLoopMode.commonModes)
        outputStream.open()

        // From now on you can write to the stream!
    }
}

// MARK: MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate
extension MPCPeripheralViewController: MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {

    func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
        joinSession()
    }

    func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}

extension MPCPeripheralViewController: MCSessionDelegate {
    func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
        switch state {
        case .connected:
            print("Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
        case .connecting:
            print("Connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")
        case .notConnected:
            print("Not Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
        }
    }

    // You probably aren't going to receive data on a peripheral connection!
    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {}

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {}

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {}

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL?, withError error: Error?) {}
}

extension MPCPeripheralViewController: StreamDelegate {
}






// The Central device!

import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

class MPCCentralViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    var mcAdvertiserAssistant: MCAdvertiserAssistant!
    var peerID: MCPeerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
    var mcSession: MCSession!
    var stream: InputStream?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mcSession = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .required)
        mcSession.delegate = self
    }

    // Hook this up!
    @IBAction func findDeviceButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        startHosting()
    }

    func startHosting() {
        mcAdvertiserAssistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "StackOverflow", discoveryInfo: nil, session: mcSession)
        mcAdvertiserAssistant.delegate = self
        mcAdvertiserAssistant.start()
    }
}

// MARK: MCSessionDelegate
extension MPCCentralViewController: MCSessionDelegate {
    func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
        // Utility debug method - check how our session is doing
        switch state {
        case .connected:
            print("Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
        case .connecting:
            print("Connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")
        case .notConnected:
            print("Not Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        print("Received some data")
    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        // Stop advertising once we're receiving a stream
        mcAdvertiserAssistant.stop()

        print("Received stream!")
        stream.delegate = self
        stream.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode:RunLoopMode.commonModes)
        stream.open()
    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {}

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL?, withError error: Error?) {}
}

// MARK: MCAdvertiserAssistantDelegate
extension MPCCentralViewController: MCAdvertiserAssistantDelegate {}

// MARK: StreamDelegate
extension MPCCentralViewController: StreamDelegate {

    func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
        // Deal with your snazzy new stream here!
    }
}
```